# Confusion with regex matching "question marks"

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have few URLs as given below:

```
www.xyz.com/search/example?x=123
www.xyz.com/search/example
```

I want to retrieve "the string between last slash and question mark (if exists)" i.e., for the above examples, I want to retrieve "example". For this I used the below regex, but its not working. Could someone please explain me why its not working. I checked in "https://regex101.com/" for explanation, but their explanation seems to match with what I am thinking, but that isn't how it is working. There is some issue in matching question marks, "\?*" is not working to match one or more question marks.

```
.*\/(.*?)\?*.*
```

FYI, I am able to write that following regex to work with my use case:

```
.*\/((?:[^?])*)
```

**My doubt is why the below regex is not working:**

```
.*\/(.*?)\?*.*
```

Comment: `\?*` matches zero or more ? marks

Comment: Yes, but it is not working like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive lookahead based regex.

```
\/([^\/?]*)(?=[^\/]*$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sT7mK2/1)

or

```
(?<=\/)[^\/?]*(?=[^\/]*$)
```

or

```
.*\/(.*?)(?:\?|$)
```

Your last regex won't work because `\?*` matches zero or more `?`. Make your regex to match `?` if exists or make it match until the line end. `(?:\?|$)` expects a `?` or line end next to the match.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```
.*\/([^\?]+)
```

which matches "all non-question-mark characters in a string with minimum length 1". Important to escape the `?` (`\?`) because it is a reserved character for `0 or 1`. Be aware, that this expects at least one character after the last `/` (`i.e. www.xyz.com/search/example/?` would result in `example/`). If that should be avoided, replace the `+` with `*` match all-length string not containing a `?` :

```
.*\/([^\?]*)
```

Regarding your question, why the `.*\/(.*?)\?*.*` does not work. The `(.*?)` part matches all strings of any character (`.`) of any length (including 0-length) that is there or not (`?`), so basically it matches the empty string. The tailing part `\?*.*` matches all strings that may or may not start with a arbitrary number of ?, so it basically matches all strings and is equivalent to `.*`